# GCC 4.3.4 and CLANG 3.5 compatiblity

Tags: gcc, c++11, clang

I am building project which based on C++11 so it needed at least GCC 4.7.2 which is not installed on my platform (and I dont have permission to upgrade software on it). So another option is to build the project with Clang and I downloaded and build CLang 3.5. On platform GCC 4.3.4 is preinstalled.

When I compiling the code I got a lot of errors like that one:

```
[ 88%] Building CXX object system/CMakeFiles/Grappa.dir/tasks/TaskingScheduler.cpp.o
cd /home/frolo/grappa/build/Make+Release/system && /home/frolo/llvm/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang++   -DENABLE_RDMA_AGGREGATOR -DGASNET_CONDUIT_IBV -DGASNET_IBV -DGASNET_SEQ -DSHMMAX=1844674407
3709551615 -std=c++11 -Winline -Wno-inline -mno-red-zone -O3 -g -I/home/frolo/grappa/build/Make+Release/third-party/include -I/home/frolo/grappa/build/Make+Release/third-party/include/ibv-condu
it -I/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-1.6.4/include -I/home/frolo/grappa/system -I/home/frolo/grappa/system/tasks    -o CMakeFiles/Grappa.dir/tasks/TaskingScheduler.cpp.o -c /home/frolo/grappa/system/tasks
/TaskingScheduler.cpp
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/Barrier.cpp:24:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/Barrier.hpp:26:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/ConditionVariable.hpp:27:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/Message.hpp:27:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/MessageBase.hpp:33:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/ConditionVariableLocal.hpp:27:
/home/frolo/grappa/system/tasks/TaskingScheduler.hpp:178:25: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream<char>')
          std::ofstream f(FLAGS_stats_blob_filename);
                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.3/fstream:571:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '::fLS::clstring' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 
'const char *' for 1st argument
      basic_ofstream(const char* __s,
      ^
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.3/bits/fstream.tcc:916:25: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from '::fLS
::clstring' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'const std::basic_ofstream<char>' for 1st argument
  extern template class basic_ofstream<char>;
                        ^
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.3/fstream:556:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
      basic_ofstream(): __ostream_type(), _M_filebuf()
      ^
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/IncoherentAcquirer.cpp:24:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/IncoherentAcquirer.hpp:28:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/Message.hpp:27:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/MessageBase.hpp:33:
In file included from /home/frolo/grappa/system/ConditionVariableLocal.hpp:27:
/home/frolo/grappa/system/tasks/TaskingScheduler.hpp:178:25: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream<char>')
          std::ofstream f(FLAGS_stats_blob_filename);
                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.3/fstream:571:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '::fLS::clstring' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 
'const char *' for 1st argument
      basic_ofstream(const char* __s,
      ^
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.3/bits/fstream.tcc:916:25: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from '::fLS
::clstring' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'const std::basic_ofstream<char>' for 1st argument
  extern template class basic_ofstream<char>;
```

...

It looks like incompatibility between gcc 4.3.4 and clang 3.5, does not it? I am not an experienced user of clang, what can be done here to mend it?

Thank you for any help!

Best,
  Alex

Comment: If you can download and install clang, why can't you download and install gcc?

Comment: Hm.. I thought it would be easier to use clang.

Comment: Using clang in combination with GCC 4.3.4's libstdc++ seems like a very bad idea to me. If you do use clang, use it with either libc++, or with the libstdc++ of a newer version of GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang 3.5 uses the [gcc 4.7 ABI](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#major-new-features) so you should compile with gcc >= 4.7. Alternatively, you can download nightly LLVM/Clang builds in .deb format for Ubuntu/Debian based Linux distros from [**this site**](http://llvm.org/apt/).